# Logback TCP syslog conforming RFC 5424

Tags: logging, tcp, logback, syslog

I'm trying, with logback, to send logging messages in a remote syslog, using TCP, and conforming to [RFC 5424](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424).

As far as I understand, logback default's syslog appender only handles UDP. So far I've found a [logback-syslog4j](https://github.com/papertrail/logback-syslog4j) library on github which handles TCP. But it doesn't seem configurable enough to send RFC 5424 compliant messages.

Is there a configuration / a library I overlooked, or should I code my own implementation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a few days of research, my best conclusion is that I should use log4j 2 instead.

Indeed, for the two features I was looking for (TCP and RFC 5424), a patch has [already been proposed](http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-588)... 6 years ago! But it has never been integrated into master. (also, I tried to gather more info on the [dev mailing list](http://mailman.qos.ch/pipermail/logback-dev/2015-June/010142.html), but never get any reply yet.)

On the other hand, log4j 2 already has [those features](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#SyslogAppender); and as far as I can see, their community seems very reactive.